# ¿Cómo obtener archivos csv mediante ajax?

Tags: python, ajax, django, csv

Estoy trabajando con django, estoy realizando la conexión de un formulario con ajax, lo que hago es:

Mediante ajax, envío un archivo csv para poder procesarlo en en mi action del formulario. Al momento de recorrer el archivo también tengo que generar un archivo csv, hasta aquí no tengo problema.

Aquí mi código para general el archivo:

```
def  upload_csv(website_data = {}):
        response = HttpResponse( content_type='text/csv') 
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="archivo_nuevo.csv"'

        writer = csv.writer( response )

        writer.writerow(['ID', 'Partner', 'Email', 'Usuario', 'Contraseña'])

       return response
```

Aquí no hay problema, se genera el archivo, pero al momento de mandar mi response al ajax me sale un error:

> TypeError: Object of type 'HttpResponse' is not JSON serializable

Mi repuesta al ajax la mando así:

```
return JsonResponse(
        json.dumps(response),
        content_type="application/json"
    )
```

Ya intente varias cosas, pero no puedo lograr mandar los datos.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: cuando usas JsonResponse debes poner algo asi: return JsonResponse(myData, safe=False)

Comment: otro punto es que tu json esta mal formado por eso te sale ese error

Comment: lo que te recomiendo es no retornar por ajax el csv, sino invocar o llamar a la url o view que genera dicho archivo mediante un boton ejemplo:   <a href ="/excel_agencia" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-sm" id="excel">
                     Reporte Excel
                </a>

Comment: Básicamente es que no puedes devolver un archivo dentro de un JSON. El error se debe a que la librería JSON no sabe como volver tu clase `HttpResponse` un objeto de JSON, por lo que debes añadirle un serializador y explicarle cómo debe hacerlo. Pero te estás complicando mucho, ya que lo primero que haces es escribir la respuesta como archivo